# Google Sheets API security

Tags: python, security, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

If I set up a Google Sheets API instance and a Google Drive API instance and then connect to the Google Sheet using the credentials key from a python script (application) on my desktop. This script performs basic CRUD operations.

My question:
Is this connection secure? In other words does the data travel over the Internet plain text or encrypted?

If not secure...how can I ensure the data securely travels from python script to Google Sheets?

I have searched for API data integrity but no luck finding out if the connection to the API need TLA or SSL.

Answer (score 0):

The network calls are secure since they must be using https calls and thus are not transported in plane text.  Post a link to the python script if you want someone to check here.

You do have to trust google with all your data.